# git.exe init # timeout=10 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' hudson.plugins.git

Tags: devops

Need your help in resolving the below error.

I am able to run git clone command from my pc, but when I am trying to run it from jenkins I am getting below error.

Error:

```
Building in workspace C:\Tools\Jenkins\jobs\project A\workspace
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@github.com:scmgalaxy/helloworld-java-maven.git
 > git.exe init C:\Tools\Jenkins\jobs\project A\workspace # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init C:\Tools\Jenkins\jobs\project A\workspace
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:656)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:463)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1039)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1079)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: git.exe init C:\Tools\Jenkins\jobs\project A\workspace
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1726)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1695)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1691)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1321)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:654)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git.exe" (in directory "C:\Tools\Jenkins\jobs\project A\workspace"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1715)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to set the path to `git.exe` in Jenkins:

1. You have to go to http://yourjenkinsserver:8080/configureTools/
2. There should be a field next to `Path to Git executable`.
3. Put in that field the path to your `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Fix.
1. There is a space in project name. So removed the space.
2. There should be a field next to Path to Git executable
3. Put in that field the path to your git.exe.
4. Define JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on windows slave, you need to add git tool location under Node Properties.

Make sure to give git executable path along with git.exe

[image: Windows node configurations]

Answer (score 0):

Except for step answered by kristian, you need config your node properties for your server side, the Tool Locations if your local is windows system, refer to below screenshot:

**tool location for your server side :**

[image: tool location for your server side]